# Calling mysql_insert_id() not working in drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I am inserting a row in a moodle database from drupal and want to get the id of the last inserted row but i am getting nowhere.
Here is my code.

```
                $moodle_database = array(
                      'database' => 'moood',
                      'username' => 'root',
                      'password' => '',
                      'host' => 'localhost', //52.23.83.176
                      'driver' => 'mysql',
                    );

                    Database::addConnectionInfo('moodle_db', 'default', $moodle_database);
                    db_set_active('moodle_db');


                    try {

                    $question_query ="INSERT INTO mdl_question ".
                       "(category,parent,name,questiontext,generalfeedback) ".
                       "VALUES ".
                       "('$category','$parent','$name','$questiontext','$generalfeedback')";
                        $queryResult=db_query($question_query);
                        $id = mysql_insert_id($queryResult);
                      }

                    catch (Exception $e) {
                      drupal_set_message(t('Exception while fetching question data ' . $e->getMessage()));
                    }

                    db_set_active();
```

Comment: Please visit this url `https://www.drupal.org/node/151718`, may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code if your using Drupal 6 :

```
db_last_insert_id('mdl_question', 'your_primary_key_id');
```

If using Drupal 7 refer below link :

```
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58991/how-to-retrieve-last-mysql-insert-id-from-drupal-7-db-merge
```

Comment: it doesnot recognixe it as a function

Comment: What version of drupal you are using.

Comment: Call to undefined function db_last_insert_id() this is the response i get

Comment: i am using drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 6 , use `db_last_insert_id();`.

In Drupal 7  `InsertQuery::execute()` returns last_insert_id.

Comment: shall i write my insert query in InsertQuery

Comment: $id = db_insert('mytable')
  ->fields(array(
    'field1' => 'value'
  
  ))
  ->execute();